# addEventListener outside IIFE stops it from working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, iife

So I read allot I should wrap my code in IIFE's, to help keep scopes clean minimizing potential errors. I found I need to use some variables created in one file, in another - and so want to put them in the global scope (or outside the IIFE).

**Issue:** When I attempted to remove IIFE my `addEventListener` stops working. As you can see in brackets it is showing that it can find the functions once I remove the IIFE.

**With IIFE**
[image]
**Without IIFE**
[image]

And in case it helps the code:

```
"use strict";
//Search the LS for the user input
function findSearchInput() {
    //Get search input
    let searchInput = document.querySelector("#searchInput").value;
    //Search array of show objects in LS for input or alert empty
    let showList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("showList") || alert("Empty"));

    for (let i = 0; i < showList.length; i++) {

        if (searchInput === showList[i].title) {
            let foundShow = showList[i];
            document.querySelector("#resultTitle").innerHTML = foundShow.title;
            document.querySelector("#resultGenre").innerHTML = foundShow.genre;
            document.querySelector("#resultType").innerHTML = foundShow.type;
            document.querySelector("#resultWatched").innerHTML = foundShow.watched;
        };
    };
};

 document.querySelector("#searchBtn").addEventListener("click", findSearchInput);
 document.querySelector("#randomBtn").addEventListener("click", findRandom);
```

If what I've said here is slightly off I do apologise I'm new to this. Can explain further if you need anything answering.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your "Without IIFE" screenshot shows only the *beginning* of the IIFE is removed, not the end of it. So the whole thing is a syntax error and nothing will run; that could easily be putting your IDE's parser off.

Comment: Other than that, there's no significant difference in the code you've shown other than that `findSearchInput` will be global without the IIFE and not with it. It doesn't affect the timing of when the code runs, etc. If the problem you're having isn't just that you forgot to remove the IIFE, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: I think it's possible that the calls to `document.querySelector` are happening before the page has finished loading, which may not have been the case with the time it took to define and execute the IIFE. It might be worth wrapping the code inside a callback handling the `load` event on `window` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load#Window)

Comment: Sorry, I should have removed that also, the event is still dead when I remove the bottom part of the IIFE, will update now.

Comment: @msbit - No, the *timing* of both pieces of code is identical, IIFE or no.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'd tend to agree, but it's worth taking a look if nothing else comes up.

Comment: I've not used the snippet tool before so may take a minute. Will definitely update though. Apologise.

Comment: @msbit - :-) Due respect, it's not about agreeing or disagreeing. It's a fact of how JavaScript runs.

Comment: I'm running into an issue when I use the snippets and minimise the code. I am storing onto the local storage in my component and it seems it errors when I try to use it within the snippet so I can't get the function to work within the site tool. I can, however, get enough on there that allows you to add/remove the IIFE and it shows the function being 'picked up/and dropped'. Is that enough?